# How to replace root with an array field during MongoDB aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have a `users` collections, with a `roleIds` field containing an array of `Role` references.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$match:{ _id: ObjectId('5f9453b4484d206714c02a2f') }}, 
  {$project:{ roleIds: 1, _id: 0 }}, 
  {$unwind: "$roleIds"}, 
  {$lookup:{ from: "roles", localField: "roleIds", foreignField: "_id", as: "roles"}}, // <= STEP 4
  {$replaceRoot: "$roles"}
])
```

After STEP 4, I have something like this:

```
{ 
  "roles" : [ 
    { "_id" : ObjectId("xxxx"), "name" : "role1" },
    { "_id" : ObjectId("xxxx"), "name" : "role2" },
  ]
}
```

How can I transform it to this:

```
[ 
  { "_id" : ObjectId("xxxx"), "name" : "role1" },
  { "_id" : ObjectId("xxxx"), "name" : "role2" },
]
```

The `replaceRoot` stage seems to work only if the roles field is a document, not an array, It throws an error in this case.

Comment: can you provide some sample documents?

Comment: `{ $unwind: "$roles" }` deconstruct array before `$replaceRoot`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$match:{ _id: ObjectId('5f9453b4484d206714c02a2f') }}, 
  {$project:{ roleIds: 1, _id: 0 }}, 
  {$unwind: "$roleIds"}, 
  {$lookup:{ from: "roles", localField: "roleIds", foreignField: "_id", as: "roles"}},
  {$unwind: "$roles"},
  {$replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$roles" }}
])
```